# Return data from retrofit onResponse

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Im doing a basic android app that performs a simple login againts an API. I need to return the received data but the retrofit onResponse method has void return type. My code is:

```
package com.example.deberesloginjava.data;

import android.util.Log;

import com.example.deberesloginjava.data.APIServices.Post;
import com.example.deberesloginjava.data.model.LoggedInUser;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.example.deberesloginjava.data.APIServices.APIService;
import com.example.deberesloginjava.data.APIServices.ApiUtils;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

/**
 * Class that handles authentication w/ login credentials and retrieves user information.
 */

public class LoginDataSource {

    private APIService mAPIService;

    public void getData(Callback<Result<LoggedInUser>> callback){
        apiClient.getData().enqueue(callback);
    }

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {

        try {

            mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

           mAPIService.login(username, password, "password").enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                        LoggedInUser loggedInUser;
                        loggedInUser = new LoggedInUser(response.body().getUserName(),response.body().getUserName(), response.body().getAccess_token());
                        return new Result.Success<>(loggedInUser);
                    }
                }



                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API.");
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }
    }
}
```

I have found at least two questions like this and both have almost the same solution with callbacks but im not able to replicate it in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to return in actual? else do you wan to to navigate to another view on successful login attempt with a Toast?

Comment: The recommended way of using retrofit is to model your responses into data classes

Comment: There is no way to do this in java as asynchronously. You should take a look at kotlin suspend functions if you want a return type other than void while not blocking the ui thread.

Comment: @Blu I want to return a Result<LoggedInUser> with the authenticated user data to show it with a Toast. The base that I have used is the default Android Studio login template.

Comment: @titanlux619 check my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add custom callback for handle this case. you can't return anything inside onResponse() and onFailure()

```
public interface CustomCallback {

    void onSucess(Result<LoggedInUser> value);
    void onFailure();
}
```

Update your method like this:

```
public void login(String username, String password,CustomCallback customCallback) {

        try {

            mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

           mAPIService.login(username, password, "password").enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                        LoggedInUser loggedInUser;
                        loggedInUser = new LoggedInUser(response.body().getUserName(),response.body().getUserName(), response.body().getAccess_token());
                        customCallback.onSucess(new Result.Success<>(loggedInUser));
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API.");
                    customCallback.onFailure();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStactTrace();
        }
    }
```

You have to call your api like below:

```
login("user name","passwor",new CustomCallback(){
       @Override
       public void onSucess(Result<LoggedInUser> value){
      //do your success code here
     }
       @Override
       public void onFailure(){
      }

});
```

Comment: Ive used this code as a base and with some changes related to my especific case it finally works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cant return a value , instead you can try making a method for passing/storing data in DTO & call that method in your `respose.IsSuccessful`. Pass the object of response json to the method for storing your required stuffs like token, username n etc,.

You can try making it like

```
               if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // just a loader untill all operations are done
                    progressBar.SetVisibility(View.Visible);
                    //Make a toast here for successful login
                    LoggedInUser loggedInUser;
                    loggedInUser = new LoggedInUser(response.body().getUserName(),response.body().getUserName(), response.body().getAccess_token());
                    UserDTO(loggedInUser);//it will save the users login details.
                }
                else{
                    //Make a toast as per your responce error.code as Invalid Password or any other error
                }
```

In UserDTO() you can create a login session for the user for auto login when user uses the app for next time, he doesnt need to enter ID & Password again. 
After all processing Navigate to your desire View `StartActivity()`

Hope this is what you are trying to achieve.